# How to install Social Auth LinkedIn PHP Library with composer for Open Social Drupal module?

Tags: 8, composer

How to install Social Auth LinkedIn PHP Library with composer for Open Social Drupal module ?

I try to install Open Social (https://www.drupal.org/project/social) but I can't because I can find how to install the LinkedIn library with Composer.

I already installed successfully Google, Facebook and Twitter library with Composer.

"Social Auth LinkedIn module requirements
Not installed
Social Auth LinkedIn requires LinkedIn PHP Library. Make sure the library is installed via Composer."

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [composer.json](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/social/tree/modules/custom/social_auth_linkedin/composer.json) of that module, you need `happyr/linkedin-api-client`. So to install that with Composer, from the root of your Drupal project run:

```
composer require happyr/linkedin-api-client:1.0.0
```

Since that library has dependencies too, you probably need [to install them too](https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client). Basing on the documentation, you could need to execute the following too.

```
composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter
composer require guzzlehttp/psr7 php-http/message
```

Comment: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.  - happyr/linkedin-api-client 1.1.x-dev requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - happyr/linkedin-api-client 1.0.0 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for happyr/linkedin-api-client ^1.0 -> satisfiable by happyr/linkedin-api-client[1.0.0, 1.1.x-dev].`

Comment: What happens if you just use `1.0.0` instead?

Comment: `Problem 1
    - Installation request for happyr/linkedin-api-client 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by happyr/linkedin-api-client[1.0.0].
    - happyr/linkedin-api-client 1.0.0 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.`

Comment: `Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.`

Comment: Check the GitHub page for that package. It looks like it has prerequisites to installing it: https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem : `composer require php-http/curl-client guzzlehttp/psr7 php-http/message happyr/linkedin-api-client`

Answer (score 0):

I installed

```
composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter
composer require guzzlehttp/psr7 php-http/message
```

and then installed

```
composer require happyr/linkedin-api-client:1.0.0
```

and it worked